# c# fill hashtable when defining

Tags: c#

Is it possible to fill a hashtable when it is first defined?

For example, here is some similar PHP code:

```
var $AA = new array("one" => 1, "two" => 2);
```

I would like to do something like this in C#. In fact, it is quite possible Hashtable is not the best tool.

take care,
lee

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look into the collection initializers - yes, it's possible. For dictionaries, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx). You can declare your dictionary and fill it with a collection of key/value pairs.

A simpler example than MSDN provides:

```
var MyDictionary = new Dictionary<string,int>()
{
    {"one", 1},
    {"two", 2}
};
```